# ​ Reset Data Picker in Adalo

Tags: android, mobile, action

I have Data Picker and I use it to filter Events in ADALO app.

[image]

But I want to be able to see all post not the filtered one. So when I want to see only posts from 1.5.2023 I will pick the 1.5.2023, but once when I finished I want to delete the date and see all posts not only the filtered ones. I probably want to reset the Data Picker when I load the screen or when I click on x icon.

How can I do that?

I thought about some custom action, but I don't know how to do that.